# how to solve root login to my server

Tags: ftp

In my IP I have a root user and respective password. Using this credentials, I login from ftp client.

From last two days back, it was hacked by strangers and I cant able to login using ftp client, which says password is incorrect.

So I changed the password in cpanel for root user. Now I am connecting from ftp client but I am seeing this following error.

```
Status: Connecting to myip...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=5
Command:    open "root@myip" 22
Error:  Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to myip...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=5
Command:    open "root@myip" 22
Error:  Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I previously, created a SSH keys in cpanel, enable authorization and downloaded key then tried login using that key in ftp client. That was also not success.

Then I disable the authorization and delete the keys.

Still I am not able to login using ftp client to root user. But I am able to login to http://myip:2086/ using this credentials.

What I need to do now?

Comment: Do you have a similar problem connecting with `ssh`?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse..

Comment: "hacked by strangers" => reinstall OS and restore data from backups. Check BIOS.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, can you please help me in this? please provide some steps in this?

Comment: @Ratwanska: Insufficient information. Is server self-hosted, colo, virtual? What provider? What OS and version? How did you make your daily backups?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, provider is BlueHost, OS is Cent OS 6.7, As we are unaware so far didn't get backups. Can you please suggest what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

The attacker has obviously disabled login with password on both of the services.

a) If your server has KVM available, you should be able to use that to revert the attackers changes. To re-enable password login you would need to modify the configuration files and restart the services (ssh, ftp).

b) If you created the SSH keys in cpanel before the attack - then the attacker could have deleted your public key from ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. Create new key pair, authorize it and try again.

c) If you already tested this, then verify that you are indeed sending correct identity with ssh client ( parameter -i '/path/to/private-key' ).